# Mono Tools for Visual Studio - tutorial wanted

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mono

I downloaded Mono for Windows and Mono Tools for Visual Studio 2010, installed them, and see some new shiny menus and Project templates in my VS now.  But I have no idea how to build my first iPhone app.  Is it even possible?  Do I need anything else besides what I have already downloaded?

Looking for help resources.  A "hello world" tutorial that takes me from starting a project to seeing it run on my iPhone/iPad would be awesome.  Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 2):

Mono Tools for Visual Studio does not allow you to build iPhone apps.  The product you are looking for is MonoTouch, which only works on a Mac, due to using a large part of Apple's development toolchain.

Comment: Installing "Mono Tools for Visual Studio" added a "MonoTouch" project template folder into Visual Studio, though.

Comment: That's a bug that is fixed internally for the next release. You will note that nothing in there is actually a project template.